# Windows 8 Messaging tile is missing

Tags: windows, windows-8

Earlier i used to chat via windows 8 messaging metro tile. Now suddenly its gone. I haven't uninstalled it. The calendar is there, the mail is there but i don't see the messaging tile.

I dont want to unistall and reinstall the entire metro app. How to bring back the messaging tile?

Comment: Right click (or slide from bottom to top) to bring up the context menu, then select "All apps" and search for your messaging app. Right click (or long touch) and select "Display on start" or "Pin on start". If should be there again (if it's really not uninstalled).

Comment: I think i have unpinned the messaging tile. The whole app consistis of Mail, Calendar etc. Only the Messaging tile is not show. Not even in all apps. Had i uninstalled it all the tiles, Mail, Calendar should have gone as well

Answer (score 1):

If you type Windows+Q from the Start Screen and search for "Messaging" do you see the app in the results list?  If so, right click on it in that list, and the App Bar will show.  From there you can re-pin the app to the Start Screen.

Comment: thanks looks like ill have to reinstall the entire app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling fixed the problem. The messaging tile is back and the Mail, Calendar and People was not touched.